# JQuery error array list items adding jump links to form labels

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, hyperlink, each

I have a list of form labels pushed into an array which will be displayed as an error list feedback message at the top of the page. I want to make each list item a link which would jump to the associated form field. How can I update the following code to add links to the array items linking to the associated form elements?
So far I have the following code:

```
var errorsArray = [];
var errorFree = true;

$('#SubmitButton').click(function(event) {

$( ".Required" ).each(function() { // Validate required form elements

// if statements handling various validations, only included one basic example. 
if ($(this).next().is(':input') && !$(this).next().val() { //validating field
  var fieldName = $(this).text();
  errorsArray.push(fieldName); 
  errorFree = false;    
}

if (!errorFree){ // If errors exist: value is false

  var list = '<ul class="errorList"><li class="errorListItem">' + errorsArray.join('</li><li class="errorListItem">') + '</li></ul>';

  $('<div id="MainAlertMessage"><p class="errorAlert">Please check the following information:</p><br>' + list + '</div>').insertAfter($('#FormTitle'));

  errorsArray.length = 0;

} else {
  alert('No errors: Form will be submitted'); // Form is ready to be submitted
}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

Just created a variable for each form element ID:

```
var alertID = $(this).next().attr('id');
```

Then using this variable I can add the named anchor link to the array.

```
errorsArray.push('<a href="#'+ alertID +'">' + fieldName + '</a>');
```